# Improving a dplyr solution -- Create a variable by conditional ordering (position) based on other information

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

I'm working on a dataset where every participant (ID) was evaluated 1, 2 or 3 times. It's a longitudinal study. Unfortunately, when the first analyst coded the dataset, she/he did not assign any information about that.

Because all participant have age information (in months), it's easy to identify when was the first evaluation, when was the second and so on. In the first evaluation, the participant was younger than the second and so on.
[image: Dataset -- Columns and information]

I used tidyverse tools to deal with that and everything is working. Howerver,I really know (imagine...) there is many other (much more) elegant solution, and I came to this forum to ask for that. Could someone give me thoughts about how to make this code shorter and clear?

This is a fake data to reproduce the code:

```
ds <- data.frame(id = seq(1:6),
                 months = round(rnorm(18, mean=12, sd=2),0),
                 x1 = sample(0:2), 
                 x2 = sample(0:2),
                 x3 = sample(0:2),
                 x4 = sample(0:2))

#add how many times each child was acessed
ds <- ds %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(how_many = n())
#Add position
ds %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(first = min(months), 
         max = max(months), 
         med = median(months)) -> ds

#add label to the third evaluation (the second will be missing)
ds %>% 
  mutate(group = case_when((how_many == 3) & (months %in% first) ~ "First evaluation",
                           (how_many == 3) & (months %in% max) ~ "Third evaluation",
                           TRUE ~ group)) -> ds
#add label to the second evaluation for all children evaluated two times 
ds %>% mutate_at(vars(group), funs(if_else(is.na(.),"Second Evaluation",.))) -> ds
```

This is my original code:

```
temp <- dataset %>% select(idind, arm, infant_sex,infant_age_months)
#add how many times each child was acessed
temp <- temp %>% group_by(idind) %>% mutate(how_many = n())
#Add position
temp %>% group_by(idind) %>% 
  mutate(first = min(infant_age_months), 
         max = max(infant_age_months), 
         med = median(infant_age_months)) -> temp

#add label to the first evaluation
temp %>% 
  mutate(group = case_when(how_many == 1 ~ "First evaluation")) -> temp

#add label to the second evaluation (and keep all previous results)
temp %>% 
  mutate(group = case_when((how_many == 2) & (infant_age_months %in% first) ~ "First evaluation",
                           (how_many == 2) & (infant_age_months %in% max) ~ "Second evaluation",
                           TRUE ~ group)) -> temp

#add label to the third evaluation (the second will be missing)
temp %>% 
  mutate(group = case_when((how_many == 3) & (infant_age_months %in% first) ~ "First evaluation",
                           (how_many == 3) & (infant_age_months %in% max) ~ "Third evaluation",
                           TRUE ~ group)) -> temp
#add label to the second evaluation for all children evaluated two times 
temp %>% mutate_at(vars(group), funs(if_else(is.na(.),"Second Evaluation",.))) -> temp
```

Please, keep in mind I used search box before asking that and I really imagine other people can figure the same question when programing.
Thanks much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go. I used `rank()` to give the order of the treatments.

```
ds <- data.frame(id = seq(1:6),
             months = round(rnorm(18, mean=12, sd=2),0),
             x1 = sample(0:2), 
             x2 = sample(0:2),
             x3 = sample(0:2),
             x4 = sample(0:2))

ds2 = ds %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(rank = rank(months,ties.method="first"))
labels = c("First", "Second","Third")
ds2$labels = labels[ds2$rank]
```

Comment: Incredible! Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

Or just arrange by age and use `1:n()` instead of `n()`, which creates a sequence:

```
ds <- ds %>% group_by(id) %>% arrange(months) %>% mutate(how_many = 1:n())
ds %>% arrange(id, months)

# A tibble: 18 x 7
# Groups:   id [6]
      id months    x1    x2    x3    x4 how_many
   <int>  <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>    <int>
 1     1     10     1     2     0     1        1
 2     1     11     1     2     0     1        2
 3     1     12     1     2     0     1        3
 4     2     11     0     1     2     2        1
 5     2     14     0     1     2     2        2
 6     2     14     0     1     2     2        3
```

You can then use `factor` to attach a label, if you wish.

```
ds$label <- factor(ds$how_many, level = 1:3, label = c("First", "Second","Third"))
head(ds)
# A tibble: 18 x 8
# Groups:   id [6]
      id months    x1    x2    x3    x4 how_many label 
   <int>  <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>    <int> <fct> 
 1     1     10     1     2     0     1        1 First 
 2     1     11     1     2     0     1        2 Second
 3     1     12     1     2     0     1        3 Third 
 4     2     11     0     1     2     2        1 First 
 5     2     14     0     1     2     2        2 Second
 6     2     14     0     1     2     2        3 Third
```